# How to remove horizontal scrollbar in flexbox appearing on Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am trying to work on a site but on firefox and IE the last section with 3 images has horizontal overflow while there is none on Chrome. I divided that `article` area into a flexbox so I thought it would handle the overflow and resize it to fit, which chrome seems to do but firefox and IE don't? The last section i'm having trouble with is `.other`. Here's my css setting up the initial layout and css pertaining to the `.other` section and `article` section:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: auto;
}
article {
  flex: 2;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
aside {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.other {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}
.fitness,
.education,
.pastimes {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

http://173.246.106.179/test.html

Comment: Jeff, please read and try to follow this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the necessary code in the question to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question. We're happy to help, but asking us to sort through your minified CSS is a bit too much. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay I edited the css down to the only relevant parts thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have stripped it out for our convenience.. but are you using an auto prefixer at all? If not, this might be why you are seeing different behaviours across browsers.

```
display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

If you are using LESS there is a nice flexbox mixin library https://gist.github.com/jayj/4012969

Always worth checking http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox too in case the browser you are testing on doesn't support flexbox yet. Coverage is quite good if you use vendor prefixes.

Comment: Heya thanks for the reply, no I've just started doing html and css I didn't know that was a thing, so it seems that different browsers interpret css differently and vendor prefixes are something that adjust for that? Just trying to get a better grasp on things.

Comment: Hm I tried adding the prefixers and it didn't seem to work. When the screen resolution isn't large enough the horizontal scroll bar shows up, on firefox and internet explorer.

Comment: have you got a codepen or jsbin example to show us your code with auto prefix?